Doubt using limit epsilon delta definition
I need help in how to prove the limit of the following function using episilon-delta definition
$$
\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)\neq 4
$$
$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{if} \quad 0 < x < 2 \\
x+3 & \text{if} \quad x \geq 2\\
\end{cases}
$$
I can prove using lateral limits, but don't know how to approach to prove using episilon-delta definition.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Recall the definition of a limit and assume towards the contradiction that $\lim_{x\to 2}g(x) = 4$. For all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $|x-2|<\delta$ implies $|g(x)-4|<\epsilon$. Let $x = 2+\delta/2$. We then have that the $|x-2| = |\delta/2| $ which is indeed less than $\delta$. However; $|g(x)-4| = \Big|\big[(2+\delta/2) + 3\big] - 4\Big| = |1+\delta/2|$. We can then see that if we choose $\epsilon < 1$ then we have reached a contradiction.
